# Running a single NVT via OpenVAS?

Tags: vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, openvas

OpenVAS has many NVTs, and running regular scans is very noisy.

1. Is it possible to run a single NVT on a target (e.g., IP address and port)?
2. If possible, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes it's possible, but it's not particularly pretty and I'd recommend against this route if you need to do this for more than a handful of NVTs.
2. In the GUI this can be achieved by creating a new Scan config. Click on Scan Configs (under Configuration), and then click on the star icon in the top left to create a new one. Name the configuration as desired, make sure that in base "Empty static, and fast" is checked (This is the default), and press enter.

   In the screen that will appear you can select NVT families. To the right of each family is the icon of a wrench. If you click on the wrench next to a family a new menu will appear enabling individual selection of each test. You can check only the one you want. Click on save. After creating a scan config you need only select in when you create a task next time.

**Bonus**; Next to each individual test in the scan config creation is a wrench. You can click it to edit variables (most commonly timeout) in the NVT.